# Ckeditor in Rails, can't set authentication session-driven

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ckeditor

I have a Ckeditor textarea in Rails 4, using `gem "ckeditor"`. All works fine, and it's placed in an administration interface. So, when I click 'browse server' to upload the assets, it links to the url:
`http://localhost:3000/ckeditor/pictures?CKEditor=skill_description&CKEditorFuncNum=1&langCode=es`

The problem is that I don't want anybody to be able to access this page, only the administrator. So I use the gem cancan (supported by the ckeditor gem) to do it.

```
class Ability
    include CanCan::Ability

    def initialize(user)
        can :access, :ckeditor   # needed to access Ckeditor filebrowser
        can [:access, :read, :create, :destroy], Ckeditor::Picture
        can [:access, :read, :create, :destroy], Ckeditor::AttachmentFile
    end
end
```

The problem is that the logic for cancan goes in a Model, so I can't get sessions there. If a make a `before_filter` in `ApplicationController`, somehow the app doesn't pass through it when going to the previous url. I think that with cancan the best way is to create a User model and create a is_admin field, but that's no what I want at this moment. Any ideas for how to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for this issue.
Create a controller under controller with name ckeditor/pictures_controller.rb.

```
class Ckeditor::PicturesController < Ckeditor::ApplicationController
  before_action: something
  def index
    @pictures = Ckeditor.picture_adapter.find_all(ckeditor_pictures_scope)
    @pictures = Ckeditor::Paginatable.new(@pictures).page(params[:page])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render :layout => @pictures.first_page? }
    end
  end

  def create
    @picture = Ckeditor.picture_model.new
    respond_with_asset(@picture)
  end

  def destroy
    @picture.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to pictures_path }
      format.json { render :nothing => true, :status => 204 }
    end
  end

  protected

    def find_asset
      @picture = Ckeditor.picture_adapter.get!(params[:id])
    end

    def authorize_resource
      model = (@picture || Ckeditor.picture_model)
      @authorization_adapter.try(:authorize, params[:action], model)
    end
end
```

Or you can find the ckeditor controller in Ruby2.1.0\lib\ruby\gems\x.x.x\gems\ckeditor-x.x.x\app\controllers\ckeditor. In there, you can custom it.